# Finding Specific word in a pandas column and assigning to a new column and replicate the row

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I am trying to find specific words from a pandas column and assign it to a new column and column may contain two or more words. Once I find it I wish to replicate the row by creating it for that word.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

wizard=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Python\L\Book1.xlsx'
                    ,sheet_name='Sheet1'
                    , header=0)

test_set = {'941', '942',}
test_set2={'MN','OK','33/3305'}
wizard['ZTYPE'] = wizard['Comment'].apply(lambda x: any(i in test_set for i in x.split()))
wizard['ZJURIS']=wizard['Comment'].apply(lambda x: any(i in test_set2 for i in x.split()))
wizard_new = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(wizard.values,3,axis=0))
wizard_new.columns = wizard.columns
wizard_new.head()
```

I am getting true and false, however unable to split it.

[image]

Above is how the sample data reflects. I need to find anything like this '33/3305', Year could be entered as '19', '2019', and quarter could be entered are 'Q1'or '1Q' or 'Q 1' or '1 Q' and my test set lists.

```
ZJURIS = dict(list(itertools.chain(*[[(y_, x) for y_ in y] for x, y in wizard.comment()])))
def to_category(x):
    for w in x.lower().split(" "):
        if w in ZJURIS:
            return ZJURIS[w]
    return None

   Finally, apply the method on the column and save the result to a new one:

wizard["ZJURIS"] = wizard["comment"].apply(to_category)
```

I tried the above solution well it did not

Any suggestions how to do I get the code to work.

Sample data.

```
data={ 'ID':['351362278576','351539320880','351582465214','351609744560','351708198604'],
'BU':['SBS','MAS','NAS','ET','SBS'],
'Comment':['940/941/w2-W3NYSIT/SUI33/3305/2019/1q','OK SUI 2Q19','941 - 3Q2019NJ SIT - 3Q2019NJ SUI/SDI - 3Q2019','IL,SUI,2016Q4,2017Q1,2017Q2','1Q2019 PA 39/5659 39/2476','UT SIT 1Q19-3Q19']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Based on the data sample data set attached is the output.

Comment: Can you give us a sense of the actual data frame you are working with? A sample subset would help

Comment: @davidbilla I have added sample data and how the output needs to look like. The Output is only for the 1st ID. It needs to be similar for the others as well. As you would notice the comment column is free text the user enters it as per their choice.

Comment: I think you need to give the separator to the `split()` function. The default separator is space. You can also use `re.split()` and pass multiple separators like this --> `re.split(', |- ', x)`. In this case, it takes ',' and '-' are separators. Moreover, I am not sure how you want to identify the values of 940, 941, 33/3305 SUI, NY etc from this comment value `'940/941/w2-W3NYSIT/SUI33/3305/2019/1q'`. For example, we can split by '/' and identify 940 and 941, but how would you identify 33/3305. I am not sure about the logic behind this.